# Determining if a Linear Operator is Diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Consider $S : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ defined via
$[x, y, z] \mapsto [5x, 5y, 3z]$

I am just a little confused with this problem. I currently have written out the coordinates for this operator $\{[5,0,0],[0,5,0],[0,0,3]\}$ to help understand the problem a little more. But, I do know that a symmetric matrix must be diagonalizable. Also, I don't see how this is not diagonalized already. Would I just need to cite the symmetry theorem and say that it is diagonalizable?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is already diagonal.

Comment: Consider the matrix of the linear map with respect to the standard basis!